# Which value is referenced to show capacity by davfs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webdav

I know there is no way to know REAL SIZE of volume through webdav protocol,
so MS Windows' is showing the SAME SIZE OF THE SYSTEM DRIVE. (usually, C:)

ref : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2386902

Then, which value is referenced by davfs in ubuntu 14.04?

In my  case>

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                                                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                      46G   22G   22G  50% /
none                                                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                                          2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                                         395M  1.5M  394M   1% /run
none                                                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                                          2.0G  152K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none                                                          100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
http://127.0.0.213/uuid-4d4f02fb-6d34-405f-b952-d00eb350b9ee   26G   13G   13G  50% /home/jin/mount/webdavTest
```

I used 50G disk and root partition(sda1) is 46G, but Total size of webdav is 26G and used 13G.

I can't determine what kind of rule(?) was used to show the webdav size and couldn't find the DOCUMENTATION about this anywhere.

Someone knows about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a way to communicate the real available space via the quota properties:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4331

It's pretty widely supported, apparently just not by Windows.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I didn't know that webdav protocol support to get real size. But unfortunately, not only windows but also davfs on ubuntu14.04 does not support quota-available-bytes, because my webdav volume has newly created only with 2G while df command shows 26G :(

Comment: Oh, I forget the word "It seems". I don't really know whether davfs supports quota properties or not.

Comment: Very surprised that davfs does not support it! Looking at the source though, it seems like they definitely check the server for those properties. See: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/davfs2/src/webdav.c?root=davfs2&view=markup and search for 'quota'.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I checked HTTP packets with Wireshark and found quota properties in PROPFIND and Multi-status response with 404 status. . According to document that you linked, just webdav server did not return properties. Davfs suports quota properties very well! And then...like this case(server did not response any quota information), which value is referenced to show disk space by davfs..? (came back to my original question)

Comment: It seems there is no more answers. But your answer was really helpful for me. thank you for your informative answer!

Comment: @earthling I know this kina old post, but can you share your wireshark data?  Trying to figure out what linux davfs2 is looking for.  Far as I know, I'm sending the right data in the xml props, according to the wevdav specs I can find, but it's not showing as expected.  Same prob with RaiDrive and ExpanDrive free versions, but maybe they not looking.  Wrote my own vanilla WevDAV server in NodeJS.  Mostly working really well.  This seems like kina important topic to address.